# Can you use the association bonus to post a bounty on one of your alt accounts' questions?

Tags: discussion, bounties, sock-puppets

I'd like some clarification on the rules for having alt accounts/sock puppet accounts. I suspect I have seen someone doing this, and think it is exploitative.

Account X posts a question on a site.
Account Y gets the association bonus from activity on other sites, and then posts a bounty on Account X's question. This is their only activity on that site.

Is this a valid use of alt accounts, or does it contravene the golden rule: [don't do anything you couldn't do with just one account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/256282)?

Comment: Very similar question: "[Transferring reputation points between accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78355/282094)", from 9 years ago.

Answer (score 15):

No, you can't.

The golden rule of sockpuppet accounts is that they should *never interact*. In this case, you are using one account to place a bounty on your second account's question. This means added attention to the second account's question, thus gaining rep for that account.

**Your accounts should never interact in any way on the way on the main sites.** The sole exception might be editing *if* the editing account is above 2k rep (i.e. won't be gaining rep from suggesting edits). **When in doubt, avoid it.**

(I mention *on the main sites* because chat is a bit different - "science" and chatbots are a bit looser in the rules about interactions.)

Comment: The bounty also prevents the reputation from being deducted from the main account, so that's another reason why it's abuse.